# Exportar DATATABLE en VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Hola que tal buenas noches , tengo el siguiente código que crea una tabla con 4 columnas y el número de filas es proporcionado por el usuario , esta tabla la exporto a un DataGridView pero si genero más de un millón de registros se demora un poco. Entonces quisiera saber si el DataTable se puede exportar directamente a CSV. El código que utilizo es el siguiente:

```
Sub BtnCrearClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim IDColumna As New DataColumn(txtID.Text)
    IDColumna.DataType=GetType(Integer)
    IDColumna.AutoIncrement=True

    Dim Nombre As New DataColumn(txtNombre.Text)
    Nombre.DataType=GetType(String)

    Dim App As New DataColumn(txtApp.Text)
    App.DataType=GetType(String)

    Dim Apm As New DataColumn(txtApm.Text)
    Apm.DataType=GetType(String)

    Dim TablaNombres As New DataTable(txtTabla.Text)
    TablaNombres.Columns.Add(IDColumna)
    TablaNombres.Columns.Add(Nombre)
    TablaNombres.Columns.Add(App)
    TablaNombres.Columns.Add(Apm)

    TablaNombres.Constraints.Add("Key1", IDColumna, True)

    Dim nombres As String()={"Aaron","Abel","Abelardo","Abraham","Adalberto","Adolfo","Adrian","Agustin","Alan","Alejandro",
        "Benjamin","Bernardo","Baldomero","Baltasar","Barack"}
    Dim apellidos As String()={"Pineda", "Bernal", "Espinoza", "Spindola", "Brisuela", "Gutierrez", "Escarcega", "Muñiz", "Lopez", "Martinez", "Piña",
        "Vega", "Ortiz", "Barcenas", "Lopez", "Martinez"}
    Dim aleatorio As New Random

    Dim row As DataRow
    Dim i As Integer
    For i=0 To Convert.ToInt32(txtFilas.Text)
        row=TablaNombres.NewRow()
        row(txtID.Text)=i
        row(txtNombre.Text)=nombres(aleatorio.Next(0,nombres.Length))
        row(txtApp.Text)=apellidos(aleatorio.Next(0,nombres.Length))
        row(txtApm.Text)=apellidos(aleatorio.Next(0,nombres.Length))
        TablaNombres.Rows.Add(row)
    Next

    tabla1.DataSource=TablaNombres
End Sub
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Sí, claro que puedes crear directamente un archivo csv según generas los registros.

Vendría a ser algo así:

```
Private Sub BtnCrear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnCrear.Click
    Const fieldSeparator = ";"
    Const folderPath = "C:\CSVDocuments"
    Dim headers As String() = { txtID.Text, txtNombre.Text, txtApp.Text, txtApm.Text }
    Dim nombres As String()={"Aaron","Abel","Abelardo","Abraham","Adalberto","Adolfo","Adrian","Agustin","Alan","Alejandro",
        "Benjamin","Bernardo","Baldomero","Baltasar","Barack"}
    Dim apellidos As String()={"Pineda", "Bernal", "Espinoza", "Spindola", "Brisuela", "Gutierrez", "Escarcega", "Muñiz", "Lopez", "Martinez", "Piña",
        "Vega", "Ortiz", "Barcenas", "Lopez", "Martinez"}
    Dim filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, $"{txtTabla.Text}.csv")
    Dim sw As New StreamWriter(filePath, False, Encoding.UTF8)
    sw.WriteLine(String.Join(fieldSeparator, headers))
    Dim aleatorio As New Random()
    For i=0 To Convert.ToInt32(txtFilas.Text)
        Dim fields As String() = {
            i.ToString(),
            nombres(aleatorio.Next(0, nombres.Length - 1)),
            apellidos(aleatorio.Next(0, apellidos.Length -1)),
            apellidos(aleatorio.Next(0, apellidos.Length - 1))
        }
        sw.WriteLine(String.Join(fieldSeparator, fields))
    Next
    sw.Close()
End Sub
```

La constante fieldSeparator contiene el separador a utilizar entre los campos.

La constante folderPath contiene la ruta a la carpeta en la que se debe guardar el archivo.

El Array headers contiene los nombres de los campos y se incluye como primera línea del archivo. Si no quieras incluir los nombres de los campos puedes quitar esa parte.

Por lo demás simplemente voy generando los valores igual que lo hacías tú y los voy añadiendo al archivo utilizando un StreamWriter.

Para leer y escribir datos en archivos de texto también puedes utilizar una librería gratuita como [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/). Aunque para un caso tan sencillo no creo que te merezca la pena.